# Is alignment a concern for pointers to templated objects? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm using a template nested class to store a type.  The class has no data members, but it does have template methods that return a bool as the result of type_traits comparisons.

```
// Someheader.h
#include < new >
#include < type_traits >

// ...

class foo {

private:

    template < typename T >
    class bar {

    public:

        bar ( ) { }
        ~bar ( ) { }

        template < typename U >
        bool convertible_to ( const U& hint ) {

            return std::is_convertible < T, U > :: value;
        }

        template < typename U >
        bool convertible_from ( const U& hint ) {

            return std::is_convertible < U, T > :: value;
        }

    };

    bar < void >* helper;

public:

    foo ( ) { }
    ~foo ( ) { delete helper; } // Correction from Kerrek SB here.

    template < typename T >
    foo ( const T& hint ) :
        helper ( &( ::new ( helper ) bar < T > ( ) ) )  
    {}

    template < typename U >
    bool convertible_to ( const U& hint ) {

        return helper -> convertible_to ( hint );
    }

    template < typename U >
    bool convertible_from ( const U& hint ) {

        return helper -> convertible_from ( hint );
    }
};
```

I'm a little worried about my use of placement new.  Class bar has no data members, but I don't know if pointer alignment can be an issue with template types.  Suppose that T = int, and int requires some alignment n * 2^m.  Does a pointer to a template object with template type int then inherit that requirement?

I can't seem to find anything on this topic, so my apologies if it's a silly question.

Comment: `helper` is uninitialized in your code...?

Comment: The destructor `~foo()` is pure cargo culting. None of it is necessary except for `delete helper;`.

Comment: It's initialized in the templated constructor.  In my use case for this, the default constructor doesn't produce anything with any meaning because foo is a wrapper for type-erased objects.

edit: Thank you, Kerrek SB.  I didn't know if that's the case for all implentations.

Comment: It's uninitialized in its inner use in the templated constructor. It's like `: x(x)`...

Comment: Placement new requires explicit call of destructor, not `delete` (see an example [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html)) - i.e. `helper->~bar()`

Comment: So that's why it wasn't recognized as an lvalue.  Dropping the '&' leads to a conversion problem, supporting what MSN says below.  Declaring bar < void > helper; and then writing helper ( *( ::new ( &helper ) bar < T > ( ) ) ) with appropriate adjustments elsewhere just quietly ignores that problem.  So, I have to write conversion methods.  Thanks for all the help!  I know what to experiment with next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment doesn't matter since you never use the type directly. However, this code fundamentally doesn't work the way you expect it to. It will always invoke `foo::bar<void>::convertable_to` and `foo::bar<void>::convertable_from`. Plus, it's not type safe.

Comment: I should have said thanks earlier, but anyways, thanks.  It is possible to have the compiler confirm what you say if a bar < void > is declared and worked with instead of a bar < void >*.  Also, for other readers who may land here, yes this example is definitely not type safe.  My actual code it's analogous to is, but I'm trying to find a way to get back some functionality lost under type-erasure.  If only type_traits classes could take a typeid struct!